# Fixed speed statement execution

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a SQL script that was released to a client, it was essentially looping over a data set and performing some checks on each loop object, and then reporting what action it took (if any) to a log file. When it was released it was processing 6-8 objects a second, which was fine.

Now we have made a major release, which has reduced the processing to one object per second. I cannot see any db change script that would indicate why this has occurred, and to be honest this has stumped me as to why this is happening.

This script is run against Oracle 10g, any suggestions as to where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
S

Comment: You tell us the speed on the initial release.  Do you ***know*** *(have evidence for)* the speed immediately before you upgraded?  Are you certain it hadn't degraded before the upgrade?

Comment: The initial release was immediately before the major upgrade. The volume of data it needs to process had not increased either.

Comment: @Stuie - So you did an initial release and a major update one after the other with no time elapsed?  That seems unusual.  Is this a packaged application that you release to many clients?  Or a bespoke application just for this client?  What sort of performance did you get in the test environment when you did the major release?  Did any query plans change?

Comment: The scrip is a client specific tool independent to the main application - so its release cycle is outside of major releases of the main application. When we tested it in our pseudo-live environment (similar size datasets) the performance was reduced to 2 objects per second, now in live it is 1 per second. I'm currently awaiting my slot to retest it in our pseudo environment.

Comment: Was the script previously processing 6-8 objects/second in your pseudo-live environment?  So then you expected the major release decrease performance by a factor of 3-4?  And the problem is that it is actually decreasing performance by an additional factor of 2?

Comment: Well we didn't expect the major release to have an impact on performance. There are no scripts or anything that I can see that would suggest an impact.

Comment: @Stuie - You say that when you tested the script in your staging environment, performance was reduced to 2 objects/second.  Surely, if performance was reduced from 6-8 objects/second to 2 objects/second when you tested it in the staging environment, it would make sense to expect a similar performance reduction in the live environment.  Was there some reason that you expected performance to stay the same in production when it was reduced in staging?  Did query plans change?  D you have AWR/ ASH reports before and after the upgrade?